# Compare Math expressions with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math

How can I compare two math expressions in JavaScript?
For example "1 + x" and "x + 1".

There is a JavaScript Math parser but I couldn't find the logic to compare the parsed expressions:
https://github.com/silentmatt/js-expression-eval/blob/master/test.js

Are there other options?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "compare"? What output are you expecting?

Comment: I'm looking for true/false

Answer (score 0):

You will need a computer algebra system (CAS) to be able to truly test whether two expressions are equal. The only one I know of in JavaScript is [javascript-cas](https://github.com/aantthony/javascript-cas), I'm not sure if this does what you need though. Other libraries like [math.js](http://math.js) and the mentioned [js-expression-eval](https://github.com/silentmatt/js-expression-eval) can parse expressions but miss to logic to understand whether two expressions are equal.

A pragmatic approach may be to compare the outcome of both expressions for a number of different values for `x`, and see if they have the same result. This will not always work though, for example `0/x+1` and `x-x` give the same result for every `x` but they aren't really equal.

Comment: Is it possible to reorder the AST generated by js-expression-eval by priority and compare the elements one by one? There could probably be very complicated cases but I think I only need stuff like "1 + x" == "x + 1" and "1 + 2*x" == "x*2 + 1".

Comment: I'm not sure if this is doable with `js-expression-eval`, it does not seem to give back a node tree. You can do this with math.js though: for example running `math.parse('1 + 2*x')` returns a tree of [nodes](https://github.com/josdejong/mathjs/tree/master/lib/expression/node), so you can traverse all nodes and order parameters where needed. In this case the root node will be an `OperatorNode` with properties `op=='+'`, 'fn=="add"', `type=="OperatorNode"` and `params` being an Array containing two params: an OperatorNode '*' and a ConstantNode 1, you can order these params for example by type.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to know just the equality then you can do approximate comparison:

1. extract variable names from expressions

   - you have `x+1` and `1+x` so there is single variable `x`
2. genere pseudo random or grid set of values for them

   - use some spec point from -inf to +inf like x={ -1e-10, 1e-9, .... 1e+9,1e+10 }
   - add few randoms
3. parse each expression with current variable set

   - so take first x value
   - compute expressions value for it
   - if it is not the same expresions are not the same
4. try all cases from genered data set

   - if all pass then expressions are likely the same
   - if not (even if just in one pass) then expressions are not the same

Comment: This will be complicate in my case and gives false positive. I'm looking for a true comparison.

Comment: @pablo then you have to extract variable as `x=???` from one expresion, substitute to the other one and simplify till `0=0` or not ... and that is far more complicated ... btw you can limit the false positives by proper dataset selection (for example if (x-1) is found add points around +1 ... also 1st and 2nd derivation can be of help here